# Upgrade Problem in Linux Headers

Tags: apt, upgrade

I was upgrading my ubuntu, when it stop when the upgrade was config linux headers. Can I restart the PC?

```
2014-03-28 14:19:32 configure lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1
2014-03-28 14:19:32 status unpacked lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1
2014-03-28 14:19:32 status unpacked lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1
2014-03-28 14:19:32 status unpacked lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1
2014-03-28 14:19:32 status unpacked lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1
2014-03-28 14:19:32 status unpacked lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1
2014-03-28 14:19:32 status unpacked lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1
2014-03-28 14:19:32 status unpacked lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1
2014-03-28 14:19:32 status unpacked lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1
2014-03-28 14:19:33 status unpacked lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1
2014-03-28 14:19:33 status unpacked lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1
2014-03-28 14:19:33 status unpacked lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1
2014-03-28 14:19:33 status unpacked lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1
2014-03-28 14:19:33 status unpacked lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1
2014-03-28 14:19:33 status unpacked lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1
2014-03-28 14:19:33 status half-configured lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1
2014-03-28 14:19:35 status installed lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1
2014-03-28 14:19:35 configure linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic:amd64 3.11.0-18.32 <none>
2014-03-28 14:19:35 status unpacked linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic:amd64 3.11.0-18.32
2014-03-28 14:19:36 status half-configured linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic:amd64 3.11.0-18.32
```

https://imageshack.com/i/jwbcpjp

Comment: Is there any error message? Any output that you saw? The output of `tail -n 20 /var/log/dpkg.log` might be helpful.

Comment: 2014-03-28 14:19:33 status unpacked lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1

2014-03-28 14:19:33 status unpacked lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1

2014-03-28 14:19:33 status half-configured lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1

2014-03-28 14:19:35 status installed lightdm:amd64 1.8.5-0ubuntu1

2014-03-28 14:19:35 configure linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic:amd64 3.11.0-18.32 <none>

2014-03-28 14:19:35 status unpacked linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic:amd64 3.11.0-18.32

2014-03-28 14:19:36 status half-configured linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic:amd64 3.11.0-18.32

Comment: Please edit your question and post it there, not in the comments.

Comment: Stop when grub.cfg
Found img /....
Founf image /....
then
found image memtes86+
and stop, 
stay for 30 minutes.

Comment: [Edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/440416/edit) your question and paste the full output there.

Comment: I paste in my question.

Comment: Are you upgrading with software-center GUI? It just does not close when it is ready. Are you sure it really is stuck?

Comment: Yes, stay for 30 minutes.

Comment: Weel, I restart my pc, and it has been working, tks for all

Answer (score 0):

After you posted the screenshot, I see the situation. Yes, it is stuck. The process of upgrading did call `update-initramfs` and it got stuck. 
Close the software-center, terminate it if Ubuntu asks to. Then, without reboot, open Terminal, and run 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' there. I think it will run, or at least give some more info. 
If you reboot now, you may get stuck on boot. It is solvable, but better don't until you update it all fine. 
P.S. But before doing this check one more thing!!! Check you don't have some message window open and buried under all others - the software-center may be just waiting for you to answer in that window, and the window has no icon on the left bar.